# How to use ramda to sort by last item in an array object

Tags: javascript, arraylist, ramda.js

Here's a list of parents and I want to sort the parents by their 2nd's child's age with ramda:

```
[
  {
    name: "Alicia",
    age: "43",
    children: [{
        name: "Billy",
        age: "3"
      },
      {
        name: "Mary",
        age: "8"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Felicia",
    age: "60",
    children: [{
        name: "Adrian",
        age: "4"
      },
      {
        name: "Joseph",
        age: "5"
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

How do I do on about it?  I tried doing something along the lines of

```
parents.sort(
                sortBy("-children.age"))
            );
```

Comment: Do you want only with ramda or one can solution with plain js code?

Comment: I don't mind seeing other solutions!  I just prefer Ramda because I'm trying to learn it.

Comment: It's not even in valid format mate, your children property if it's an object you can have it like this,

Comment: This is something plain JS can already do using `sort()` with a comparison function as argument. However, do parents always have 2 children? (because that seems an unlikely data property)

Answer (score 2):

Use `R.sortBy` and extract the value with a function create with `R.pipe`. The function gets the children array of the object with `R.prop`, takes the last child (`R.last`), gets the `age` with `R.propOr` (returns 0 if no children), and converts to a `Number`. You can use `R.negate` if you want to reverse the order.

```js
const { sortBy, pipe, prop, last, propOr } = R

const fn = sortBy(pipe(
  prop('children'),
  last,
  propOr(0, 'age'),
  Number,
  // negate - if you want to reverse the order
))

const parents = [{"name":"Alicia","age":"43","children":[{"name":"Billy","age":"3"},{"name":"Mary","age":"8"}]},{"name":"Felicia","age":"60","children":[{"name":"Adrian","age":"4"},{"name":"Joseph","age":"5"}]}]

const result = fn(parents)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JavaScript (making some assumptions about the relatively poorly formatted input) using the [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method:

```
let parents = [ .... ]; // What you have above
parents = parents.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.children[1].age - b.children[1].age; // Change - to + for ascending / descending
});
```

Be careful though - what would happen if a parent had fewer than 2 children?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON above was hand generated, including the syntax errors, then assuming your real data is just fine (an array of parents, with each parent having a `children` array of objects) then a normal JS sort will work just fine:

```
const compareC2(parent1, parent2) {
  let c1 = parent1.children;
  let c2 = parent2.children;

  if (!c1 || !c2) {
    // what happens if someone has no children?
  }

  let l1 = c1.length;
  let l2 = c2.length;

  if (l1 === 0 || l2 === 0) {
    // different symptom, but same question as above
  }

  if (l1 !== l2) {
    // what happens when the child counts differ?
  }

  if (l1 !== 2) {
    // what happens when there are fewer, or more than, 2 children?
  }

  // after a WHOLE LOT of assumptions, sort based on
  // the ages of the 2nd child for each parent.
  return c1[1].age - c2[1].age;
}  

let sorted = parents.sort(compareC2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `sortWith` with `ascend` functions. Using `sortWith` allows you to define a first sort order function, a second sort order function, etc.

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: "Alicia",
    age: "43",
    children: [{
        name: "Billy",
        age: "3"
      },
      {
        name: "Mary",
        age: "8"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Felicia",
    age: "60",
    children: [{
        name: "Adrian",
        age: "4"
      },
      {
        name: "Joseph",
        age: "5"
      },
    ]
  }
];

const by2ndChildAge = ascend(pathOr(0, ['children', 1, 'age']));
const by1stChildAge = ascend(pathOr(0, ['children', 0, 'age']));

console.log(sortWith([by2ndChildAge, by1stChildAge], people));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {sortWith, ascend, pathOr} = R;</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is, I think, just to combine [`sortBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sortBy) with [`path`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path):

```js
const sortBy2ndChildAge = sortBy(path(['children', 1, 'age']))

const people = [{name: "Alicia", age: "43", children: [{name: "Billy", age: "3"}, {name: "Mary", age: "8"}]}, {name: "Felicia", age: "60", children: [{name: "Adrian", age: "4"}, {name: "Joseph", age: "5"}]}]
console.log(sortBy2ndChildAge(people))
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/ramda@0.26.1"></script><script>
const {sortBy, path} = ramda    </script>
```

There are several potential flaws with this, that others have noted.  Are parents always guaranteed to have at least two children?  Do we really want a lexicographic sort -- i.e. `'11' < '2'` -- or do you want to convert these values to numbers?

It would be easy enough to fix both of these problems:  `sortBy(compose(Number, pathOr(0, ['children', 1, 'age'])))`, but that depends upon what you're trying to do.  If you're just using this to learn about Ramda, then `sortBy` and `path` are both useful functions to know.  `sortBy` is useful when you can convert the items to be sorted to some ordered type -- Strings, numbers, dates, or anything with a numeric `valueOf` method.  You supply that conversion function and a list of values and it will sort by that.  `path` is simply a null-safe read for a list of nested properties in an object.